# How to push to multiple endpoints in GCP pub/sub?

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-run

I have multiple microservices that would need to be notified of certain events. All these microservices are running on Cloud Run. Given that Cloud Run can scale down to 0 instances, I’ve assumed that the Push model is better for our situation.

The problem arises with needing to get the notification to multiple endpoints. For example, we have an OrderService, an InventoryService, and PaymentService. The latter two both need to listen for the “OrderPlaced” event. The question is, how can we push this message to both services without having to explicitly call it (e.g. with Task Queues) or creating dependencies within the OrderService? Is there a “Google Cloud” way of solving this issue?

I’ve thought about creating “pull” listeners but the problem is that Cloud Run instances can scale to 0, right, which would effectively not receive events?

Comment: It sounds like when a message gets published you want EACH of your services to be a subscriber.  That would seem to mean that you want to create THREE subscriptions against the same topic.  Each subscription would have a push binding to its corresponding Cloud Run implementation.  When a single message is published to the topic, EACH of the three subscribers would do their own processing and indepdently deliver the messages in parallel to each of the implementations.

Comment: Ah, you are absolutely right, that is exactly what I was missing. I was too focused on creating listeners that I did not realize that I could create multiple subs to the topic via the GCP console, haha. Please write it as an answer so I can accept. Thanks! Also, would I just need to repeat this then for each environment as well, or is there a better way to determine which message comes from what environment so the push can route correctly, or should I just create a new project for dev vs prod? Perhaps that is best suited to be a different question on S.O.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "repeat this for each environment" ... maybe you can elaborate on what you mean by distinct/separate environments?

Comment: Yeah, so I have two “sets” of Cloud Run containers. In one, the dockerfile sets the environment to “development” and in the other it is set to “production”. Depending on which environment it is on, during runtime different “secrets” are loaded from GCP Secret Manager. The part I’m stuck at is how to isolate dev “OrderPlaced” event from prod “OrderPlaced” event. Will I need to create separate topics like “DevOrderPlaced” or do you think I should create totally separate GCP projects altogether? Not sure the right way to tackle different environments with pub/sub and cloud run

Comment: Dr @ara06 ... what I have seen in my travels are separate GCP projects.  It is not uncommon to see projects for dev, test and prod with a common source code repository shared between them.  This allows you to keep one set of configurations, one set of binaries and as close a mapping as possible between everything so there is little/no leakage between them.  That way, you can have consistent names for topics and subcsriptions but they differ by context (dev/test/prod) which is governed by project.  I'd also look to automating infrastructure build using Terraform.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a message is published to a topic, a subscriber is made aware of that message and can be used to push a copy of the message to an application that wishes to process it.  If we have multiple applications that wish to be notified when a message is published, we can create multiple subscriptions to the same topic.  Each subscription will independently cause a copy of the published message to be pushed to its own registered application in parallel.